# connection event gets triggered infinite times for one client in socket.io

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, next.js

I am using socket.io with nextJS. In the server, I am listening to the 'connection' event.
Now when I launch the client site, the connection event in the server gets triggered infinite teams.

//pages/index.js in client

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import io from 'socket.io-client'

export default function Home() {
  const [ users, setUsers ] = useState(0);
  const socket = io();

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('user', (count) => {
     console.log(count)
     setUsers(count)
    })

    return () => {
      socket.disconnect();
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <p>Online Users: {users}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

//class based

```
class Index extends React.Component {


state = {
    users: 0,
    roomList: []
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.socket = io();
    this.socket.on('user', count => {
      this.setState({users: count})
    })

    this.socket.on('roomList', rooms => {
      this.setState({roomList: rooms})
    })
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    console.log('unmounted')
    this.socket.disconnect();
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <p>Online Users: {this.state.users}</p>
        <div>
          { this.roomList && this.roomList.length !== 0 && 
              this.roomList.map(room => (
                <li key={room}>{room}</li>
              ))
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Index;
```

Can anyone help me to figure out why its not working for functional component?

Comment: Please post the code where you are using `Home`

Comment: @VivekDoshi In next.js files under folder Pages act as a separate page. and the file named 'index.js' act as the root page '/'. Hope you have understand my point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating the socket directly in render, which means each time your functional component re-renders a new instance of socket is created.

You must use `useRef` to store an instance of socket and create it in useEffect

```
export default function Home() {
  const [ users, setUsers ] = useState(0);
  const socketInstance = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const socket = io();
    socketInstance.current = socket;
    socket.on('user', (count) => {
     console.log(count)
     setUsers(count)
    })

    return () => {
      socket.disconnect();
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <p>Online Users: {users}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Are you sur eyour useEffect has an empty dependency?

Comment: yes. I have tried with both the cases. What about my server config? is it ok?

Comment: That seems ok to me, are you sure your do not create socket instance anywher else and you replaced it with useRef

Comment: The classbased solution works. But then what is the issue with hook?

Comment: Do you mean converting Home to class component works?

Comment: Yes. I have added that component in the question.

Comment: Please check the updated answer. I think this approach will work. The previous approach has one issue

Comment: The issue with the previous approach was that even though the arguments to useRef are used only once, they are evaluated everytime since its just a function call and that would lead to a new connection instance request on your server. Writing in the above manner would fix that issue since instance is created only inside useEffect which is called just once

Comment: Its working now. But if you see your code, you are not using the ref. You set the socketInstance.current = socket. However you have not used the socketInstance after that. I have removed the ref part. It's working for me.

Comment: yes, not using the ref in current code, i have just saved socketinstance in ref in case you need to use it else where. If you don't you can avoid the use of useRef altogether

Comment: Yes. Thanks for your help. Seriously I appreciate your efforts.

Comment: Happy to help @SujoySaha.

Comment: Done! Beside the socket instance is also useful. I can send it as props to other component.

Comment: Yes, exactly the reason why we can store the reference in ref